# Connect Django to MongoLab database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mlab

I am currently running Django 1.4.3 and I want to connect my own database (created in MongoLab) to talk with my Django website. I've tried following numerous tutorials on how to achieve this; the problem I am running into in my Django settings.py file is that my database isn't setup correctly (due to not being able to connect). I am very new to Django and MongoDB so any help would be appreciated.

Here is one of the tutorials that I've followed: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/05/MongoDB-backend-for-Django-nonrel-released

Note: I am using a Mac and using Terminal to program everything if this matters.

Here is the trouble area in my settings.py (most was autogenerated by Django)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', ### This wasn't working ###
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sq$
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. N$
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not$
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x10f732210>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
from django.db import models, connection
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/django_mongodb_engine/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

File: .../django_mongodb_engine/**init**.py (This is straight from the download, No editing)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__version__ = (0, 4, 0)
__author__ = "Flavio Percoco Premoli, Alberto Paro, " + \
         "Jonas Haag and contributors"
__contact__ = "django-non-relational@googlegroups.com"
__homepage__ = "https://django-mongodb.org"
__docformat__ = "restructuredtext"

try:
    from django.conf import settings
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS.insert(0, 'django_mongodb_engine')
    # It might be irritating that django-mongodb-engine registers itself as an app,
    # and I think this is worth an explanation - so here you go:
    # django-mongodb-engine provides a way to set MongoDB-specific options for a
    # certain model via the 'MongoMeta' class/attribute (similar to the Django-style
    # 'Meta' class).  We want those options to be copied into the model's
    # '_meta' object, right after the class has been defined.
    # For this, we have to listen to the 'class_prepared' signal from
    # 'django.db.models.signals'. Because the 'django_mongodb_engine' module gets
    # imported as part of the initialization process of Django's ORM ('django.db'),
    # we can *not* import anything from 'django.db' in this file (or any other
    # submodule that is imported while the ORM initialization) because that would
    # get us into recursive import hell which the Python interpreter doesn't allow.
    # The only way to make sure certain code is executed after Django's ORM has been
    # initialized is registering an app. After initializing itself, Django imports
    # all apps defined in the project's 'settings.py' in the order implied by
    # iterating over the INSTALLED_APPS list. As we have to make sure that
    # django-mongodb-engine is loaded very first, we prepend it to the list.
except ImportError:
pass
```

Comment: can you post your settings.py, and your complete error?

Comment: Just did, although it is mainly auto-generated from Django

Comment: post the error message, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a bug.

Check [this report](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues/153).

And if you follow the links, [here](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox/issues/36) a developer says:

> mongodb-engine doesn't support django 1.4 at this time. so stick with
>   1.3.

That comment is from yesterday. So that's it, the Django version you're using is not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the values in the settings file. As you can see they are mostly empty strings. MongoLab will give you all the connection info you need on the home page for the database you created.

Comment: I took them out, I have all those correct values, I just cannot connect via the "django_mongodb_engine". I'm not sure why it won't connect.

Comment: Can you post the error message you get along with the stacktrace?(obscure all passwords)

Comment: That file is automatically created with a new project. The file is completely blank/empty.

Comment: What about this file (the one referenced in the error msg): build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/django_mongodb_engine/__init__.py

Comment: Posted it, but I haven't modified that either after downloading it from the tutorial link.